# How to Call SQLite database delete column ("db.delete") from outside the class the database was created

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am required to use a Button defined in fragment 'CheckInFragment.java' to delete data from the database defined outside the fragment. Currently, the deleteCheckIn method is located in CheckInList.java which needs to be called on the delete button defined in the fragment using an OnClickListener.

Currently, I am unable to reference or use / create this method inside the fragment.

I've tried referencing the method inside the fragment but since it requires arguments only stored in CheckInList.java it was unsuccessful. I've tried directly calling the mDataBase.delete without using a method however as the previous attempt it cannot be called without those arguments.

CheckInList.java

```
...

public class CheckInList {
    private static CheckInList sCheckInList;
    private Context mContext;
    public SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;

    public static CheckInList get(Context context) {
        if (sCheckInList == null) {
            sCheckInList = new CheckInList(context);
        }
        return sCheckInList;
    }

    public CheckInList(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mDataBase = new CheckInBaseHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //REQUIRED METHOD TO BE CALLED
    public void deleteCheckIn(CheckIn c) {
        mDataBase.delete(DATABASE_NAME,  CheckInTable.Cols.UUID + "=" + c, null);
    }
...
```

//CheckInFragment.java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_checkin, container, false);

...

mDeleteButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.checkin_delete);
        mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //call delete method here
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
...
```

//CheckIn.java (as per comments)

```
public class CheckIn  {
    private UUID mId;
    private String mTitle;
    private String mPlace;
    private String mDetails;
    private Date mDate;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;

...
   public UUID getId() {
        return mId;
    }
...

   public CheckIn() {
        this(UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    public CheckIn(UUID id) {
        mId = id;
        mDate = new Date();
    }
...
```

I would like to find a way to use deleteCheckIn when the mDeleteButton button is clicked.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CheckInList {
    ...
    // While implementing Singleton, the constructor must be private
    private CheckInList(Context context) {
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mDataBase = new CheckInBaseHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
    }
    ...
}

mDeleteButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.checkin_delete);
    mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckInList.get(v.getContext()).deleteCheckIn(/* Send the parameter here */);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks W0rmH0le! worked like a charm however now when it is called I get an SQL error ```android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: DELETE FROM checkinBase.db WHERE uuid=android.bignerdranch.mycheckins.CheckIn@dcef189``` Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is here: "CheckInTable.Cols.UUID + "=" + c" in the delete method. You are passing the "c" paramenter directly. I think you need to retrieve the UUID from the "c" parameter. Something like: c.getUUID() or c.toString... I'm not sure because you didn't share your class CheckIn

Comment: I've updated the post with the CheckIn.java class, I'd imagine in my case it would be c.getId() ? I tried c.getId() which responded with another SQL error except it is now unrecognized token.

Comment: c.getId() is correct. However, it returns another object UUID. The SQL query is expecting a String. Could you please share the class UUID as well and this new error message?

Comment: I'm sorry W0rmH0le not sure what you mean by class UUID, I added more of the CheckIn.java class which mentions the UUID's. Here is the new SQL error: ```unrecognized token: "7ac5"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "7ac5" (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: DELETE FROM checkinBase.db WHERE uuid=d21a141d-7ac5-487b-a5af-6eae0825ac37```

Comment: Try this: CheckInTable.Cols.UUID + "=\"" + c.getId() + "\""

Comment: Unforuntely it returned: ```android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: checkinBase.db (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the handler setOnClickListener create a variable CheckInList _this = this and used it to access the public and non static mDataBase

Answer (score 0):

You had to access an instance of the class and call the method to delete in the background thread.

```
mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    CheckInList dao = CheckInList.get(v.getContext());
    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      dao.deleteCheckIn(yourCheckInObjectInstance);
    });
  }
});
```